# rails model file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I obtain model file path in rails? I want something like that:

```
MyModel.file_path
```

expected result: "/app/models/my_model.rb

It's possible to do in rails or I need to create file name from models name and find it in models directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to build it, but is fairly simple.

Here it goes:

```
def model_path
  model_file = self.class.name.split("::").map {|c| c.downcase }.join('/') + '.rb'
  path = Rails.root.join('app/models/').join(model_file)
end
```

Comment: yes I know this way but I hoped it's already implemented in rails

Comment: Works within subfolders, except if you're defining your own load_paths, without using the normal class-namespacing-folder-structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__FILE__` to refer to the current file path:

```
def self.file_path
  File.expand_path(__FILE__)
end
```

or

```
def self.file_path
  __FILE__
end
```

Note that the Ruby version matters for what `__FILE__` returns. See [What does __FILE__ mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224379/what-does-file-mean-in-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

[Adapted from part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629534/221016) to a more general question]

In a simple Rails application, the application's model classes are defined within its `app/models` directory, with a file path that can be derived deterministically from the class name.  A method to retrieve this path can be defined in a specific model class `MyModel` like so:

```ruby
class MyModel
  def self.file_path
    Rails.root.join('app', 'models', "#{klass.name.underscore}.rb").to_s
  end
end
```

For example, this particular model class `MyModel` would be defined in `APP_ROOT/app/models/my_model.rb`, where `APP_ROOT` is the application's root directory path.

To generalize this, one can define such a method in all model classes and consider extensions of the simple Rails path configuration.  In a Rails application that defines custom paths for model definitions, one must consider all of them.  Also, since an arbitrary model class may be defined in any Rails engine loaded by the application, one must also look in all loaded engines, taking into account their custom paths.  The following code combines these considerations.

```ruby
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.file_path
      candidates = Rails.application.config.paths['app/models'].map do |model_root|
        Rails.root.join(model_root, "#{name.underscore}.rb").to_s
      end
      candidates += Rails::Engine::Railties.engines.flat_map do |engine|
        engine.paths['app/models'].map do |model_root|
          engine.root.join(model_root, "#{name.underscore}.rb").to_s
        end
      end
      candidates.find { |path| File.exist?(path) }
    end
  end
end
```

To make Rails apply this monkey patch, `require` it in `config/initializers/active_record.rb`.