# Naming conflict in rails with "Account" model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Account` located under `/app/models/account.rb`:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

when I now request the controller I get **`undefined method all for Account:Module`**:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end
end
```

I tried renaming the model to `Accounte` which does work. However I see a lot of rails tutorials working with `Account` models and it is really hard to find other names.

**How do I locate and disable the Account module to clear this naming conflict?**

I can access the *bad* `Account` through `rails console`.

Comment: I assume you don't have a module named `Account` in your own codebase, what gems are in your Gemfile

Comment: Do you have any gems that might be adding an `Account` module?

Comment: Also, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407131/877472), it might help you figure out where this other `Account` module is being defined.

Comment: @UriAgassi I have `rails~4.1.8`, `mysql2~0.3.17` and `spring`.

Comment: @PaulRichter I only get an empty array back with your method.

Comment: Ah I just found out that I initially ran `rails new account` so `config/application.rb` defines `module Account`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I used `rails new account` which creates a module `Account` in `config/application.rb`. This caused the naming trouble.